# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0050

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create an android app that consist of fragments in a tab activity. The tab consists of Fragment A and Fragment B(HistoryInfoFragment). Fragment B have a button for the user to click and it will shows Fragment C(HistoryDetailFragment). However, when I run the app the following error was thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0050 (com.example.test.interfacev2:id/frame_container) for fragment HistoryDetailFragment

I had refered to several other questions but still encountering the problem. Here are my codes.

TabActivity.java

```
public class TabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Current", "History"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HistoryInfoFragment.java

```
public class HistoryInfoFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_fragment, container, false);
        Button bth = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        bth.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new HistoryDetailFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        // this is the line that throw the exception
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

tabactivity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

history_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="history"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="submit"
        android:id="@+id/btn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

history_detail_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="history detail"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: add stack trace.
Not sure if this is the correct stack trace.

```
08-16 08:35:25.148    2162-2162/com.example.test.interfacev2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d52b20)
08-16 08:35:25.156    2162-2162/com.example.test.interfacev2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test.interfacev2, PID: 2162
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0050 (com.example.test.interfacev2:id/frame_container) for fragment HistoryDetailFragment{52a755dc #2 id=0x7f0c0050}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add your stack trace.

Comment: @AawazGyawali added stack trace in edit. Not sure if that is the correct stack trace you are referring to.

Comment: add your complete stacktrace or at least portion which starts with "caused by"

Comment: Add your complete stack trace, At least add after the caused by line

Comment: @AawazGyawali Sorry, I am quite new to android programming. Where can i find the stack trace that you are referring to?

Answer (score 3):

I think you use the wrong fragmentmanager in HistoryInfoFragment.java.
I had a similar problem yesterday. I had to use

```
getParentFragment().getFragmentManager()
```

and because I use my fragment sometimes without a parent the whole line looks:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragment() != null ? getParentFragment().getFragmentManager() : getFragmentManager();
```

I don't really know why you need different fragment managers at all - I think this is stupid crap which Google should have done much better or at least they should explain it in the fragment documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `FrameLayout` as you fragment layout root.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="history"/>

        <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="submit"
           android:id="@+id/btn" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I had added the framelayout but still experiencing the same error.

Comment: A quick question, are you trying to show your fragments in your Navigation Drawer? The IllegalStateException refers to R.id.frame_container, which only occurs into the drawer layout.

Comment: I am trying to show the fragments in a tab activity not a navigation drawer. The frame_container is in the activity_main.xml which the fragments will replace.

Comment: Wait, why did you post the activity_main.xml file? In your Activity code you inflated tabslayout.xml; but you inflate your Fragment with this line of code: fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); I am a little confused about your code organization, but if you want to show fragments into the ViewPager you don't need to manually call a Fragment. On the other hand, if you wanted to change Activity (from the tabs one to the main one), you should first launch that Activity through Intents.

Comment: I realize my mistake. I was trying to replace the wrong fragment container by using activity_main. I should replace the container that is containing the tab (tabactivity.xml). Sorry that I had cause so much trouble.

Comment: The reason is due to I have a mainactivity class which will load an overview fragment. From the overview fragment, it will load a tab activity class. Then from the tab activity it will load the history fragment. So all along I was trying to replace the container in the mainactivity layout (activity_main.xml) instead of tab activity layout (tabactivity,xml)

Comment: Don't worry, we're all here to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using wrong fragmentmanager.If you want to use place and manage fragment inside another fragment, you must *getChildFragmentManager()*.Otherwise,the application try to added your fragment, activity start to alive.And you'll face crash.